# How to simplify wxpython code?

Tags: wxpython

Hi I'm having problem with my code, it works perfect when in the onbutton method n takes number 100 or less as parameter. but when number is more then 100 my computer freezes and at the end it crashes. I need to simplify my code and want to make it work in any ways. any suggestions? I know that there is some sql selects in my code but don't give attention to that just think about them as numbers and text in first select it gives number of static text i want to create and in second select it takes content with what i want to fill.

```
import wx
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=10.75.79.215;DATABASE=HUB_DATA;UID=sa;PWD=password")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

########################################################################
class RandomPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)

class scroll(wx.ScrolledWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent, color):
        wx.ScrolledWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)
        self.SetScrollbars(4,4,5000,5000)



########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        topSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        hSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(topSplitter)

        panelOne = RandomPanel(hSplitter, "white")
        panelTwo = RandomPanel(hSplitter, "white")
        hSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)
        hSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        self.panelThree = scroll(topSplitter, "white")
        topSplitter.SplitHorizontally(hSplitter, self.panelThree)
        topSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topSplitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        txtOne = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1, label = "piradoba", pos = (20,10))
        self.txtTwo = wx.StaticText(panelOne, -1, label = "", pos = (40,80))
        self.txtplace = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne, pos = (20,30))
        button = wx.Button(panelOne, label = "search", pos = (40,100))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onbutton)
        self.ctrls1 = []
        self.ctrls2 = []
        self.ctrls3 = []
        self.ctrls4 = []
        self.ctrls5 = []
        self.ctrls6 = []
        self.ctrls7 = []
        self.ctrls8 = []
        self.ctrls9 = []
        self.ctrls10 = []
        self.ctrls11 = []
        self.ctrls12 = []
        self.ctrls13 = []
        self.ctrls14 = []


    def Onbutton(self, event):
        var=self.txtplace.GetValue()
        if len(var) == 9 or len(var) == 11:
            self.txtTwo.SetLabel("True")
            cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(DPVLDT) as raodenoba
                            FROM [HBGE_Reports].[dbo].[hub_DDJPFile] s
                            where exists (SELECT [ZGDCS]
                            FROM [HUB_DATA].[dbo].[SSCUSTP] d
                            where [ZGIDNO]=?
                            and
                            s.DPACS=d.ZGDCS)""",str(var))
            raw = cursor.fetchone()
            n = raw.raodenoba

            for i in range(n):
                self.ctrls1.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (20, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls2.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (120, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls3.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (220, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls4.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (320, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls5.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (420, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls6.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (520, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls7.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (620, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls8.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (720, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls9.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (820, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls10.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (920, 30 * i)))
                self.ctrls11.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (1020, 30 * i),size=(10,10)))
                self.ctrls12.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (1220, 30 * i),size=(50,100)))
                self.ctrls13.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (1420, 30 * i),size=(50,100)))
                self.ctrls14.append(wx.StaticText(self.panelThree, label = '', pos = (1620, 30 * i),size=(50,100)))



            cursor.execute("""declare @a varchar(20)
                    set @a=?
                    SELECT [DPVLDT]
                          ,[DPCPDT]
                          ,[DPACB]
                          ,[DPACS]
                          ,[DPACX]
                          ,[DPCYCD]     
                          ,[DPDLCD]
                          ,[RCY_AMOUNT]
                          ,[LCY_AMOUNT]
                          ,[DPBLBL]
                          ,[DPNAR1]
                          ,[DPNAR2]
                          ,[DPNAR3]
                          ,[DPNAR4]     
                          FROM [HBGE_Reports].[dbo].[hub_DDJPFile] s
                          where exists (SELECT [ZGDCS]
                          FROM [HUB_DATA].[dbo].[SSCUSTP] d
                          where [ZGIDNO]=@a
                          and
                          s.DPACS=d.ZGDCS)
                          order by [DPVLDT] desc""", str(var))

            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            for i in range(n):
                self.ctrls1[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPVLDT))
                self.ctrls2[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPCPDT))
                self.ctrls3[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPACB))
                self.ctrls4[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPACS))
                self.ctrls5[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPACX))
                self.ctrls6[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPCYCD))
                self.ctrls7[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPDLCD))
                self.ctrls8[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].RCY_AMOUNT))
                self.ctrls9[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].LCY_AMOUNT))
                self.ctrls10[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPBLBL))
                self.ctrls11[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPNAR1))
                self.ctrls12[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPNAR2))
                self.ctrls13[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPNAR3))
                self.ctrls14[i].SetLabel(str(rows[i].DPNAR4))









########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="test",
                          size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looping over a result-set and setting various labels. However, it also appears that you are overwriting the labels on each iteration. I'm not exactly sure why you would want to do that.

My guess at your problem is that the query is getting to be too large. Try doing the query in regular Python without wx and see how long it takes to execute. If you can measure how long it's taking, then during that time, it is blocking wxPython's main loop which is why it is freezing. To get around that, you need to put the queries into a separate thread and send the results back to wxPython to update the display.

Here are a couple of articles on the subject:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: thanks it was very helpful. Now I'm trying to find out more about treads